# Remove lines from a XML file using Python and save it as a new XML file

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have a XML file like below. I want to remove few lines from top and bottom and save it as a new xml file. I need to remove everything before and after the "measData" tag. Is there any easy way to do it in Python?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataCollection.xsl"?>
  <measCollecFile xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec">
  <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.435 V10.0"
          vendorName="Ericsson AB">
    <fileSender elementType="RadioNode"/>
    <measCollec beginTime="2020-02-20T12:00:00+00:00"/>
    </fileHeader>

 <measData>
   <managedElement swVersion="CXP9024418_6 R80E66"/>
  <measInfo measInfoId="PM=1,PmGroup=FieldReplaceableUnit">
  <job jobId="PREDEF_Nc"/>
  <granPeriod duration="PT900S"
              endTime="2020-02-20T12:15:00+00:00"/>
  <repPeriod duration="PT900S"/>
  <measType p="1">pmPowerFailure</measType>
  <measType p="2">pmUnitTemperatureLevel</measType>
  <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,FieldReplaceableUnit=1">
    <r p="1"> </r>
    <r p="2">3,3, </r>
  </measValue>
  <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,FieldReplaceableUnit=2">
    <r p="1">0</r>
    <r p="2"> , , </r>
  </measValue>
  <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,FieldReplaceableUnit=3">
    <r p="1">0</r>
    <r p="2"> , , </r>
  </measValue>
  <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,FieldReplaceableUnit=4">
    <r p="1">0</r>
    <r p="2"> , , </r>
  </measValue>
  <measValue measObjLdn="ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,FieldReplaceableUnit=5">
    <r p="1">0</r>
    <r p="2"> , , </r>
  </measValue>
  </measInfo>
  </measData>

    <fileFooter>
   <measCollec endTime="2020-02-20T12:30:00+00:00"/>
  </fileFooter>
      </measCollecFile>
```

Comment: You want to remove `fileHeader` and `fileFooter`?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, you are right

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? This is not a forum for asking how to do things, but rather get help when your attempt fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

collect = """[your xml above]"""

soup = bs(collect,'lxml')
target1 = soup.select_one('fileHeader')
target2 = soup.select_one('fileFooter')
target1.getparent
target1.decompose()
target2.getparent    
target2.decompose()
print(soup)
```

Output is the original xml without the two target nodes.